# How does Vite handle removal of .css nesting in built .css files?

Tags: css, vite

I've been working with Vite and noticed that the built .css files differ from the original source due to the removal of nesting. Specifically, Vite seems to flatten or remove nested selectors in the generated .css files.

I'm curious about the internal mechanisms or processes within Vite that result in this behavior. What specific steps or plugins does Vite utilize to handle the removal of nested CSS selectors during the build process?

I'm not using any plugins for postcss like postcss-nesting, etc.

It can be seen here:
Pre-build: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-f5jflt?file=src%2Findex.css
Post-build: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-f5jflt?file=dist%2Fassets%2Findex-MKu-Fj7f.css

I've looked through the Vite documentation and searched for related information, but I haven't been able to find a clear explanation of how this transformation occurs.

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev, could you elaborate your thoughts with at least 2-3 words rather than sending a link to the documentation? I've read this and it is not mentioned anywhere something related to Vite flattening the css out-of-the-box.

In fact they recommend for postcss-nesting to be added manually: https://vitejs.dev/guide/features#css-pre-processors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vite uses PostCSS internally, so it seems it flattens CSS automatically:

```
    "node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc": {
      "version": "3.4.5",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@vue/compiler-sfc/-/compiler-sfc-3.4.5.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-jauvkDuSSUbP0ebhfNqljhShA90YEfX/0wZ+w40oZF43IjGyWYjqYaJbvMJwGOd+9+vODW6eSvnk28f0SGV7OQ==",
      "dependencies": {
        "@babel/parser": "^7.23.6",
        "@vue/compiler-core": "3.4.5",
        "@vue/compiler-dom": "3.4.5",
        "@vue/compiler-ssr": "3.4.5",
        "@vue/shared": "3.4.5",
        "estree-walker": "^2.0.2",
        "magic-string": "^0.30.5",
        "postcss": "^8.4.32",
        "source-map-js": "^1.0.2"
      }
    },
```

But why do you need it nested? It's not supported yet well.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I do not need it nested. I am curious why would Vite un-nest it and still recommend that I add the postcss-nested plugin manually in their documentation. Seems like there is something internal happening with the building that is not well documented.

Comment: @shamana yes, i submitted bugs in the Vue documentation